# How to get the id of the td based if the text value matches exactly

Tags: jquery

How to get the id of the `td` based if the text value matches exactly?

```html
<table id="tid1">
  <tr>
    <td id="td1">George</td>
    <td id="td2">George2</td>
    <td id="td3">George3</td>
    <td id="td4">Georg</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the id of "Georg" td4 to get returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to get the element.

```js
console.log(
  // get all td with id attribute
  // or additionally use :contains to get more specific
  // $('td[id]:contains("Georg")')
  $('td[id]')
  // filter the jquery element collection
  .filter(function() {
    // compare content
    return $(this).text().trim() === 'Georg';
  })
  // get the id of filtered element
  .attr('id')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tid1">
  <tr>
    <td id="td1">George</td>
    <td id="td2">George2</td>
    <td id="td3">George3</td>
    <td id="td4">Georg</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This looks to be a better solution

Comment: this is best solution among all.+1 from my side too

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#tid1 tr').each(function() {
   $(this).children('td').each(function(j){
        var data =  $(this).html().trim();
        if(data==="Georg"){
           alert("Id of td which contain text 'George' " +$(this).attr('id'));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add a extend function below

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    alert($("tr").find("td:textEquals('Georg')").attr('id'));
    });

 $.expr[':'].textEquals = function(el, i, m) {
    var searchText = m[3];
    var match = $(el).text().trim().match("^" + searchText + "$")
    return match && match.length > 0;
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "Georg" with your desire text.

```
$("#tid1 td:contains(Georg)").each(function(){
        alert(this.id);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

$('td:contains("Georg")').attr(id)